# Python 2.7 Script works with breakpoint in Debug mode but not when Run

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets

```
def mp_worker(row):
    ip = row[0]
    ip_address = ip
    tcp_port = 2112
    buffer_size = 1024

    # Read the reset message sent from the sign when a new connection is established
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        print('Connecting to terminal: {0}'.format(ip_address))
        s.connect((ip_address, tcp_port))

        #Putting a breakpoint on this call in debug makes the script work
        s.send(":08a8RV;")

        #data = recv_timeout(s)
        data = s.recv(buffer_size)

        strip = data.split("$", 1)[-1].rstrip()
        strip = strip[:-1]
        print(strip)
        termStat = [ip_address, strip]

        terminals.append(termStat)

    except Exception as exc:
        print("Exception connecting to: " + ip_address)
        print(exc)
```

The above code is the section of the script that is causing the problem. It's a pretty simple function that connects to a socket based on a passed in IP from a DB query and receives a response that indicates the hardware's firmware version.

Now, the issue is that when I run it in debug with a breakpoint on the socket I get the entire expected response from the hardware, but if I don't have a breakpoint in there or I full on Run the script it only responds with part of the expected message. I tried both putting a time.sleep() in after the send to see if it would get the entire response and I tried using the commented out recv_timeout() method in there which uses a non-blocking socket and timeout to try to get an entire response, both with the exact same results.

As another note,  this works in a script with everything in one main code block, but I need this part separated into a function so I can use it with the multiprocessing library. I've tried running it on both my local Windows 7 machine and on a Unix server with the same results.

Comment: My initial would also be not all input ready, but since you say that's not the case... Sorry, no other guess atm, but a way around it perhaps. Does your server close the connection when done serving full response? If so, you could `recv` and concatenate until closed connection is detected (empty string returned). And continue with your script execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just recently found out a solution here, and thought I'd post it in case anyone else has issue, I just decided to try and call socket.recv() before calling socket.send() and then calling socket.recv() again afterwards and it seems to have fixed the issue; I couldn't really tell you why it works though.

```
data = s.recv(buffer_size)

s.send(":08a8RV;")

data = s.recv(buffer_size)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll expands and reiterate on what I've put into a comment moment ago. I am still not entirely sure what is behind the different behavior in either scenario (apart from timing guess apparently disproved by an attempt to include `sleep`.

However, it's somewhat immaterial as stream sockets do not guarantee you get all the requested data at once and in chunks as requested. This is up for an application to deal with. If the server closes the socket after full response was sent, you could replace:

```
data = s.recv(buffer_size)
```

with `recv()` until zero bytes were received, this would be equivalent of getting `0` (`EOF`) from from the syscall:

```
data = ''
while True:
    received = s.recv(buffer_size)
    if len(received) == 0:
        break
    data += received
```

If that is not the case, you would have to rely on fixed or known (sent in the beginning) size you want to consider together. Or deal with this on protocol level (look for characters, sequences used to signal message boundaries.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking a look! I actually just recently found out a solution here, thought I couldn't really tell you why it works. I call s.recv() before I do the s.send and then call it after I do the send call again. It gives me the correct response every time now, maybe it needed to be cleared or something? It feels like it shouldn't work but it does.

Comment: Good that it works, but keep in mind, it really does not have to hold true under all circumstances and for ever. You should not rely on that behavior as it is not not a guaranteed property of a stream.